# Practicing linked lists

Tags: c, list

So we learned about lists in class lately and I wanted to practice them. The program doesn't run. Did I fail in filling the nodes? I'm too dizzy to focus on finding the missing key. Sorry for posting such triviality!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
}node_t;


node_t* create_node(int value,node_t *nextnode) {
    node_t *newnode=(node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if(newnode==NULL) {
        printf("ERROR ALLOCATING");
        exit(0);
    }
    newnode->val=value;
    newnode->next=nextnode;
    return newnode;
}

void fill_list(node_t *head) {
    int i=1;
    node_t *current;
    for(;i<21;i++) {
        current=create_node(i,head);
        head=current;
    }
}

void print_list(node_t *head) {
    node_t *current=head;
    while(current) {
        printf("%d",current->val);
        current=current->next;
    }
}


int main() {
    node_t *head=NULL;
    fill_list(head);
    print_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The program doesn't run."?  What is it supposed to do?  What does it do instead?

Comment: It's supposed to print the elements of the list

Comment: Here you just assign to a local variable `head` `head=current;`.  It does not modify the `head` local variable in the callee.  Perhaps you should modify `fill_list` to return a pointer to a node instead, or have it take a double-pointer as an argument.

Comment: `printf("ERROR ALLOCATING"); exit(0);` seems incongruous.  The word "ERROR" strongly suggests that this is an error, but you write it to stdout and then exit with a status indicating success. That should be `fprintf( stderr, ... ); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: Is this `C++`?  That is strongly suggested by `int main()`.  Use `int main(void)` in C.

Comment: I would change the word `lists` to `linked lists` :o)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `fill_list` never returns the new head. Thus, `head` in  `main` remains `NULL`.

An easy way of changing that behaviour would be to have `fill_list` return the new head:

```
node_t* fill_list(node_t *head) {
    int i=1;
    node_t *current;
    for(;i<21;i++) {
        current=create_node(i,head);
        head=current;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the function `fill_list` the parameter `head` is being changed.

```
void fill_list(node_t *head) {
    int i=1;
    node_t *current;
    for(;i<21;i++) {
        current=create_node(i,head);
        head=current;
    }
}
```

But the function deals with a copy of the argument passed to the function. So the original pointer head defined in main knows nothing about these changes.

You have to return the value of the parameter head of the function from the function and assign it to the pointer head defined in main.

So the function can look like

```
node_t * fill_list(node_t *head) {
    for( int i = 1; i < 21; i++ ) 
    {
        head = create_node( i, head );
    }

    return head;
}
```

and in main there must be

```
node_t *head = NULL;
head = fill_list( head );
```

Another way is to pass the pointer head to the function fill_list by reference. In this case the function can look

```
void fill_list( node_t **head ) {
    for ( int i = 1; i < 21; i++ ) {
        *head = create_node( i, *head );
    }
}
```

And in main you should write

```
node_t *head = NULL;
fill_list( &head );
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Function arguments in C are 'pass-by-value'. The problem with this is that your `fill_list` function takes a pointer to a `node_t` called `head`, but any changes you make to this pointer, will **not** affect the value of `head` outside the function. `head` inside the function is a completely different thing to the  `head` in your `main()`.

**Quick Fix**

If you really want to change the value of `head` (the one outside the function) then you have to pass the function a pointer to the bit of memory in which `head` resides. For your example, this means a pointer to a pointer to a `node_t`.

So your `fill_list` would look like:

```
void fill_list(node_t **head) {
    int i=1;
    node_t *current;
    for(;i<21;i++) {
        current=create_node(i, *head);
        *head=current;
    }
}
```

Note that you must now dereference the pointer before passing it to `create_node`.

By dereferencing in the assignment `*head = current`, you are setting the contents of the memory pointed to by `head`. Which is the same memory holding the `head` variable declared in your `main()`. This is what you want.

Now you can call `fill_list` like this:

`fill_list(&head)`

**Better Fix**

Have `fill_list` return a pointer to the head, such as:

```
node_t* fill_list() {
    int i=1;
    node_t *head = NULL;
    node_t *current;
    for(;i<21;i++) {
        current=create_node(i, head);
        head=current;
    }

    return head;
}
```

and then `main()`:

```
int main() {
    node_t *head = fill_list();
    print_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```